# Force password on svn checkout

Tags: svn, ubuntu, subclipse, subversive

I have set up subversion by following http://www.maketecheasier.com/setting-up-subversion-version-control-in-ubuntu/ .Rightnow svn  checkout is not asking for password. How can this be achieved ?

Answer (score 1):

Here is the ultimate answer to your question: http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/.

Here is the chapter you must read: http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.serverconfig.httpd.html#svn.serverconfig.httpd.authn.

Answer (score 1):

From mentioned by @bahrep SVN Book

> For example, to allow **anonymous read-only operations**, you would use the **LimitExcept directive** (passing the GET, PROPFIND, OPTIONS, and REPORT request type parameters) and place the previously mentioned Require valid-user directive inside the  block instead of just inside the  block.

(Bolding is my addition)

and thoughtlessly copied from howto `<Location>` section contains **exactly this snippet**

```
<LimitExcept GET PROPFIND OPTIONS REPORT>
Require valid-user
</LimitExcept>
```